# What is the standard location for global enums in an ASP.NET Web API app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, enums, global-asax

I want to declare an enum in my ASP.NET Web API project, a member of which will be passed from the Controller to the Repository, a la:

```
enum SaveTypes
{
MSAccess,
SQLite,
CSV,
XML,
JSON
};
```

Controller

```
SaveTypes st = SaveTypes.MSAccess;
_inventoryItemRepository.PostInventoryItem(id, ... st);
```

Repository

```
public void PostInventoryItem(string id, ... SaveTypes _st)
{
    if (st == SaveTypes.MSAccess)
    {
    //give it to the fake database
    }
    else if (st == SaveTypes.FoieGrasBar) 
    ...
```

Where would be the best place to declare this enum - in a new class? In Global.asax.cs? Somewhere else?

Note: I do realize that the "right" way to do it might be to create multiple implementations of the interface implementation, one that will save to Access, another to SQLite, etc.

Comment: Looks like strictly personal preference/local coding guideline question to me... Anywhere you like should be fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for enums in ASP.NET MVC project is DataAccess directory:

> - DataAccess project
>
>   - Base
>   - Entities
>   - Enums
>   - Repositories
>   - ...
> - Site project
>
>   - Controllers
>   - Models
>   - Views
>   - Services
>   - ...